# iOS - Pie progress bar with rounded corners

Tags: ios, animation, progress-bar

I need to implement a progress bar according to this design :

[image]

As you can see, there is a corner radius to the bar itself.

This is how it looks now with my current code :

[image]

So, how to do that?
This is my current code:

```
- (void)animateProgressBarToPercent:(float)percent
{
    if (percent > 1.0f) return;

    int radius = 42.7f;
    int strokeWidth = 7.f;
    CGColorRef color = [UIColor someColor].CGColor;
    int timeInSeconds = percent * 5;

    CGFloat startAngle = 0;
    CGFloat endAngle = percent;

    CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius) cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;
    circle.position = CGPointMake(self.center.x - radius, self.center.y + strokeWidth);
    circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    circle.strokeColor = color;
    circle.lineWidth = strokeWidth;
    circle.strokeEnd = endAngle;

    [self.layer addSublayer:circle];

    CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    drawAnimation.duration            = timeInSeconds;
    drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0;
    drawAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:startAngle];
    drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:endAngle];

    drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

    [circle addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
circle.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
```

Just set this property of your `CAShapeLayer`